# Why is there buoyant force acting even if the object is in complete contact with bottom ofcontainer

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If our object is in complete contact with the bottom surface of our fluid container  let us say water container then why is buoyant force still acting because buoyant force is generated due to the pressure difference in the upper and bottom surface of our submerged object however in the end buoyant force is generated because water applies upward force on our object from below  but if the object is in contact with bottom of our container so no water should be present below our object and hence no buoyant force should act . Anyway please answer me this question also I study in 10 th standard in india so please try to use easy language/ concept to make me understand this .